# How to decide where to handle an exception - in scope of function it been thrown or in global one?

Tags: c++, exception

I`m writing client-server app for windows using WinSock and I have class for server.
while initialising server I have such code:

```
class Server {
    static const int MaxClients = 10;
    std::vector connections;
    CRITICAL_SECTION cs;
    int port;
    SOCKET ServerSocket;
    sockaddr_in ServerAddress;
    void init(); 
public:
    Server(int Port);
    void addConnection(const Client& newClient); 
    void closeConnection(int index); 
    void Listen();
    int size(); 
    /*virtual void ClientService();
    virtual void SendMsg(const std::string& msg);*/
    virtual ~Server();
};

void Server::init() {
    WSADATA wsaData;
    if(WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData))
        throw Exception("WinSock init failed");
    ServerSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (ServerSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
        throw Exception("Socket failed to create!");
    ServerAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
    ServerAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY); 
    ServerAddress.sin_port = htons(port);
    if(bind(ServerSocket,(sockaddr*)&ServerAddress,sizeof(ServerAddress)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        throw Exception("Binding failed");
        closesocket(ServerSocket); 
    }
}
```

where do I need to handle exceptions? Here, in init() private method (which is called from constructor) or in main function? 
Any rules existing where to place handlers for exceptions and what does it depend on?

Comment: Note that your closesocket() call just after throwing the exception would never get executed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on whether you're actually going to *handle* the exception, e.g. retry with a slightly different input, or decide to ignore the problem and proceed anyway (rarely appropriate, but *can* be useful). In this case, you may well want to catch the exception close to its source.

In most cases, the only thing you can really do with an exception is log it and abort the operation (e.g. serve the user an error page in a web app, or pop up a friendly "this program has crashed, sorry" dialog and exit). In this case, your catch block is likely to be quite close to the top of the stack - e.g. in the main method.

Answer (score 4):

The basic rule is that you only catch exceptions in that part of the code, where you can actually *handle* it.  By handling it I mean that you can take some action based upon the exception thrown, for instance trying to create the socket another time, or trying to use a different configuration.

Additionally, exceptions which cross library-boundaries need to be reviewed.  Depending on the context you may want to catch them and rethrow a different type of exception, for instance to hide implementation details from the library client.

Answer (score 0):

As for the question about catching the exception in the scope of the function where it's thrown (ie., in the `init()` function) - it seldom makes sense to catch an exception in the scope where it's thrown.  In essence that would mean that you've detected an error and know how to handle it (and are going to handle it), but that you're using an exception to perform nothing more than a transfer of control to another part of your function.

While there might be cases where this might make sense (though that would be a code smell that indicates the function is complex enough that it should be refactored), the logic for handling that error (since it *is* being handled) should use more common control flow techniques such as `if` statements or a `break`.  Even the wildly unpopular `goto` might be preferable to throwing an exception only to have it handled in the same function.